# Foreach in LINQ statement, is this possible?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers. I am running a repository to retrieve data, however. I need to do a where on the list of integers. I am wondering how I can go about this and whether it is even possible. For example I need to do something like this:

```
join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
                       on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
                   equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
                   where d.ClaimID == foreach(var item in IntList) {
                       d.ClaimId == item.ClaimID
                   }
```

I'm know the syntax isn't right but if it was, I wouldn't be here! So i'm wondering if this is possible and if not, what is the best way to go around this?

Comment: Please specify what you are intending to do. Your pseudocode is hard to understand.

Comment: For completeness of the code, please also include `from d in <someTable>`

Comment: @MichałKędrzyński Sorry, my intention is to return an IQueryable list of data based on multiple ClaimIDs.

Comment: hi @AndrewKilburn did any of the provided answers help you out? If yes, please mark them as accepted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your questions correctly, you can use the following syntax

```
join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
                   on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
               equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
               where IntList.Select(x => x.ClaimID).Contains(d.ClaimID)
```

Comment: If this is an EF query you'll probably need to project the list of `IntList.ClaimID`s _outside_ of the query.

Comment: that might be correct but since OP didn't specify which or-mapper he uses, its the general answer. but of course you can project the list outside of the query and use the pojected list inside :)

Comment: Not saying you were wrong, just pointing out a potential issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try linq method [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb548541(v=VS.110).aspx)

```
join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
    on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
    equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
where IntList.All(item => d.ClaimId == item.ClaimID)
```

Or [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
    on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }
    equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
where IntList.Any(item => d.ClaimId == item.ClaimID)
```

So, difference is when all elements of IntList must match `d.ClaimId` use `All`, if you need at least one - use `Any`.

Comment: `All` returns a `bool` and I don't think `ClaimID` is a `bool`.

Comment: Though I have to wonder if they really want `Any` instead of `All`, but the question isn't very clear on that point.

Comment: @juharr yes, added both versions